# How to run Jersey with the built in web server from Java SE 6?

Tags: java, jersey, java-6

I don't want to use Tomcat, Jetty or an Java EE 6 container to offer REST services but the built in web server.

Comment: Good question. It seems there is no help for Java SE users when it comes to web services. And not everyone wants a web server in the Enterprise sense... I hope there is some more examples or help posted here.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure that you have Jersey's `jersey-server.jar` in the classpath, then it's as simple as:

```
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:9998/");
server.start();
```

Pick whatever port you want to use.

Comment: @wjl: The question is about how to run Jersey with the built in web server of Java SE. The question is not about how to configure/prepare Jersey for being run on an arbitrary server. It's the same for all servers.

Answer (score 1):

For Jersey 2.x you will need **jersey-container-jdk-http** in your classpath. If you are using maven add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
     <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To start the server use this:

```
URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(10000).build();
ResourceConfig resourceConfig=new ResourceConfig(WebService.class);
HttpServer httpServer=JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, resourceConfig,true);
```